# Can I display twovalues in a Silverlight TextBlock?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Can I data bind two proporties values in a single textblock.

For Example some thing like following, though this is noth the correct code:

```
 <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding property1,Binding property2}" Style="{StaticResource Style1}" />
```

I want to display two values in a single text block .

Thanks,
Subhendu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use MVVM you would typically create a third property that concatenates the two others and bind to that one.

```
public string Prop1 { get; set; }

public string Prop2 { get; set; }

public string Prop3 { get {return string.Format("{0} {1}", Prop1, Prop2); } }
```

In you xaml, you would then  bind to Prop3.  If you want two way binding, you can implement a setter for Prop3 that updates Prop1 and Prop2.

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

mmm, AFIK you can't do that.

however, you CAN do it a couple of ways.

One, create a [Converter](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx) that takes your object and returns the two properties

```
    public class Formatter : IValueConverter
    {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
              // do some stuff with value to get your information
              return myvalue;
       }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

}
```

// make a static resource of your converter

```
<Resources>
    <myns:Converter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Resource>
```

// now use it in your binding

second, you can nest textblocks like so (well, maybe not in silverlight, but in WPF you can) ...

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock .../>
    <TextBlock .../>
</TextBlock>
```